# why won't my code work? new to java

Tags: java

I am very new to the whole CS scene but quickly getting into it, I chose Java as the first language I wanted to learn.

I'm using an online resource that asks me to make a simple program which asks the user to enter a number, and then it spits back out the sum of the powers.

So if you input 4, I want it to give you 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4  This is what I have so far, but it's not working, any suggestions?

I am using NetBeans.

```
System.out.println("Type a number: ");
int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
int i = 0;
int exponent = (int)Math.pow(2,i);
int sum = 0;
while (i <= number) {
     sum += exponent;
 i++;
}
System.out.println("The result is: " + sum);
```

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Are you getting a specific error message? Does it quit without any output? Does it summon Yog Sothoth?

Comment: `int exponent = (int)Math.pow(2,i);` needs to be in the loop.

Comment: You are supposed to recompute `exponent` at each iteration .

Comment: "*Not working*" is not informative. Provide a fuller description of your problem. [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    int exponent = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    while (i < number) {
        sum += exponent;
        i++;
        exponent = (int) Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    System.out.println("The result is: " + sum);
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. The condition required is `i <= number`. Also, the calculation with the `exponent` variable is wrong as it's not adding the last number.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry !

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a value to `exponent` outside the loop.

This means that it's value won't change every time `i` is incremented.

To fix this:

```
    System.out.println("Type a number: ");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
        sum += Math.pow(2,i);
    }
    System.out.println("The result is: " + sum);


}
```

In addition to producing the desired output, this code is more efficient as I've removed the `exponent` variable (as it can be added straight to `sum`), and I've used a `for` loop (so that there's no need for the line where `i` is declared or for the line where `i` is incremented).

Comment: Thanks, I just put it inside the loop and it worked. So in general is it better to make variables inside the loops when that's the only place they're used?

Comment: @Cade It depends. If you're changing the value of the said variable in each iteration of the loop, then yes. However, if the variable isn't supposed to change inside the loop, then no.

Comment: @Cade Please can you accept this answer if it worked for you as this will help people in the future who encounter your problem? (as they'll know which solution worked for you)

Answer (score 0):

Whole case with for loop

```
public static void test(){
    java.util.Scanner reader = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type a number: ");

    int sum = 0;
    int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

    for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++){
        int exponent = (int) Math.pow(2, i);
        sum = sum + exponent;
    //    System.out.println(i); if you want to see the exponent uncomment this line
    }

    System.out.println("The result is: " + sum);
}
```

Comment: It can be even shorter without sum:
int exponent = 0;
exponent += (int) Math.pow(2, i);